# ios Parse Facebook Permissions not being read

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, permissions

I call this code to present my login view controller:

```
  LoginViewController *logInViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        [logInViewController setDelegate:self];

        [logInViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil]];

        [logInViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsDismissButton];

        [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

In the Parse Documentation, notice I do the following in that method to ask for Facebook permissions:

```
   [logInViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil]];
```

When I try login in the permissions are not being read and it logs in me without asking for permissions?

How come Parse isn't reading my permissions I have set, I have looked everywhere for an answer but I can't find one?

Here is an image of my login screen, it simply says I have already authorised my app instead of saying this app asks for the email permission.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you already agreed with the fact that your app asks for your email, as it's written on the view.
Know that when you ask for permissions and the user accepts them, Facebook keep it in mind, so the user doesn't have to accept EVERY SINGLE TIME he login on your app.

So I think it just mostly means that the first time you tried to login with Facebook on your app you agreed with the mail accessing and that's all :)

Hope it helps \o

Comment: I originally thought this was the case, but whenever I call this.
   `if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"email"]) {
        NSLog(@"Email Permission has been granted");
    }else{
          NSLog(@"Email Permission has NOT been granted");
    }`

The Log always returns that the permission has NOT been granted.

Comment: So it can be because you didn't set that permission on your App description on Facebook developpers I think :x I had a problem 3 days ago, I asked the publish permission for my app, but nothing was published on Facebook, and the FBLoginView never asked me (as a Facebook user) for a permission to publish content on Facebook. And I saw we didn't set those permission on the app on the Facebook dev center...now we are waiting ´cause Facebook review our app for that and hope it will resolve the situation. I think you're in this case :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion however my email permissions has already been granted, you can see from the link of an image I uploaded below. http://postimg.org/image/l1helfw55/

Comment: And on your app description on the Facebook developpers portal ? And I know they made some big changes in the framework with the methods we have to use for the permissions, try using the last SDK version if you don't ?